# Data-binding ObservableCollection<T> with ComboBox doesn't work with Dependency Property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, dependency-properties

I have a list of objects (ObservableCollection subjectlist) and want to display them in a Combobox via data-binding and dependency property.

[WPF Data Binding to a Combo Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784715/wpf-data-binding-to-a-combo-box)

I searched on stackoverflow and tried to implement the solution of Craig Suchanec in the link above. (tried the whole day now and I just don't get what's wrong with my code)

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SubjectListProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SubjectList",
        typeof(ObservableCollection<Subject>),
        typeof(MainWindow));



    private ObservableCollection<Subject> subjectList = new ObservableCollection<Subject>();
    Initialization init1;


    public ObservableCollection<Subject> SubjectList
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Subject>)GetValue(SubjectListProperty); }
        // get { return subjectList; }

    }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        init1 = new Initialization();
        subjectList = init1.createMenuSubject();

        InitializeComponent();
        //this.comboBox.DataContext = SubjectList;
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
   <Grid>

    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="321,10,0,0"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow, Path=SubjectList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>

   </Grid>
```

It DOES work if I just set the DataContext and work without dependency property, but as soon as I try to use the dependency property for data-binding it does NOT and I don't see the significant difference between my implementation and the solution given in the link.

It would be much appreciated, if somebody could help me with this problem.

Comment: Please post the actual code in your question, instead of screenshots. Code formatting is easy, just indent by four spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anywhere in your code where you are actually setting the value of the SubjectList property.

You are however setting the value of subjectList, but you're binding to SubjectList. Note the casing difference.

Comment: Omg, thank you! I changed subjectList to SubjectList and wrote a set. Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You should write:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Subject> SubjectList
    {
        set { base.SetValue(SubjectListProperty, value); }
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Subject>)base.GetValue(SubjectListProperty); }
    }
```

instead of

```
    public ObservableCollection<Subject> SubjectList
    {
        set { base.SetValue(SubjectListProperty, value); }
        get { return subjectList; }
    }
```

or any other ad hoc format. You are setting *subjectList* in your constructor *MainWindow()*, however, it will not set the value of *SubjectList* (with Capital S) and a property change event is never raised. Remove *subjectList*.

If you are wondering why the *DataContext* approach works, you should note it will work even if you do not use a *DepenedencyProperty*. However, if you implement *INotifyPropertyChange*, it will work with setting *ElementName* too.

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed subjectList to SubjectList in the constructor and edited the accessor. Now it is working!